# How does transparency in rgba work?

Tags: css, rgba

I have recently learned about rgba for setting colours in css. I am curious about the technical aspect of the transparency channel actually works.

For example, if I set the values to be rgba(15, 34, 160, 1) and rgba(15 34, 160, 0.5) for two separate headers, then they are referred to as having the same colour, but having a different opacity value. What I am wondering is whether or not these colours are actually the same. By this I mean that in terms of the light coming out the pixels, they must surely be different in order to create two different looks of headers. Does this mean that the alpha value is actually used to change the colour in some sort of specific way?

Cheers!

Comment: very simple if you set `opacity:0.5` it means the header will be a mix 50% **/** 50% with the page background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you can "half see" the color of the element behind a half-transparent element, it will be mixed with that color (if the background is white, it will appear lighter, if it's black, darker, and if it's another color there will also be a mixture of the colors.

So, technically it's the same color with different transparency, but the perceived result will be a different color (unless by chance the element behind the transparent one has the same color)

Answer (score 0):

An RGB value is a color, an RGBA value is a color plus transparency. When you overlay it on a colored background, it can result in a different apparent color. So yes, they are the same COLOR, but can result in different colors depending on where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpkn8chk/1/)

Play with the the top CSS property that looks like this:

```
background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.7);
```

The last value there is the opacity (opposite of transparency) measured from 0 to 1. 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque. The first three values are just like a regular rgb() CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

By setting an RGBA color value. You are really just setting the color and a separate opacity value. This could be accomplished by setting the color with RGB and then the opacity separately with opacity, but RGBA combines the two into a single function.  Using RGBA is shorter, but setting RGBA and then opacity separately allows you control over the values separately.

So, your two examples are setting the same value for color, but applying two different levels of opacity to that color.